# How to tell Apache to use just one .htaccess file and not request any other ones?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, apache2, virtualhost

Can I tell Apache that I have just one `.htaccess` file on my application?

For example, if I have a `.htaccess` file inside my `public_html` and I have `AllowOverride` not set to `none` on my Virtual Host, the [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/howto/htaccess.html#page-header) says for each HTTP request that I have, the Apache server will try to find the `.htaccess` files on the current directory and on the high-level ones.

But I would like to keep just one `.htaccess` file on the entire application and I don't want Apache to try to find `.htaccess` files on the current directory and the high-level ones, **but just read the `public_html/.htaccess` file**.

The motivation for this is because I'd like get a website hosting, but I am not allowed to change my VirtualHost. So, to perform server actions, `.htaccess` files is allowed to me. But, if I can tell on my main `public_html/.htaccess` file, there's no other `.htaccess` files, probably my application will save a lot of processing.

Is possible to do this? And how?

How can I test if is working?

**Edit**

The [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride) says:

**Allow Override**

```
Only available in <Directory> sections
AllowOverride is valid only in <Directory> sections specified without regular expressions, not in <Location>, <DirectoryMatch> or <Files> sections.
```

So, I can't try something like `AllowOverride None` on my `public_html/.htaccess` file.
But is there a way to countour this?

Comment: Upvoted it, seems like a reasonable question. I cleaned up some of your English, but it is otherwise OK...

Comment: Did you try to put AllowOverride None in the .htaccess root? (I've never tried this, but it seems like it might work...)

Comment: @GarouDan I'm not the one who downvoted it, but it was probably because the docs you linked to uses words such as "must". The answer is that it is not possible.